# WDKRemoteUser password ?

Tags: windbg, wdf

I am trying debug a WDF drivers by connecting  Visual Studio 2013 to my test machine. It creates a user named WDKRemoteUser and it tries to auto logon while doing the tests. Anyone knows the password of this user ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't visual debug :( but a right click Google for the keyword turns up this in first page and looks like you need to set a password in Local User Group and Re-login

http://hackmridul.blogspot.in/2014/11/wdkremoteuser-woes.html

quoted below is the relevant part from the link

> What do?
>
> Solution: Log in to the target computer with an admin account. Go to
>   'Edit Local Users and Groups'.  You should see the 'WDKRemoteUser' in
>   the list. Right-click the user and 'Set Password...'. Put in a
>   password that will work  with your group password policy. Sign out and
>   login as ".\WDKRemoteUser" with your current password. Retry the
>   provisioning with the corresponding debug settings. It will run
>   through the provisioning correctly this time.